# Automatically Close ExtJS Window When Losing Focus

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I have a small window that can open in my application which allows a user to perform trivial tasks, when the user clicks outside of the window I'd like to simply close it.  Some examples suggest listening for a click event on the background *"mask"* - aside from feeling a bit hacky this isn't an option because the window isn't configured as `modal` as it's functionality is non-blocking, I don't want to restrict the UI behind it.

I had initially tried to hook onto the `blur` event however the behaviour is temperamental in ExtJS 5+ ***i.e.*** with the following example ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fg4)), try dragging or clicking outside of the window.

```js
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 500,
    height: 250,
    items: {
        xtype: 'box',
        padding: 20,
        html: 'Test window...'
    }
});
win.on('blur', win.close, win);
win.show();
```

- In ***5.1.0***  to ***5.1.1***  this fails completely.
- In ***5.1.2***  to ***6.2.0***  this works but closes unexpectedly if you try dragging by the header.

Is there some other configuration or a neat solution that covers both issues, cross-version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of fighting with the `focus` state of the component I opted for the following MVC setup which listens for a global click event and then determines whether or not the user clicked on the window.

```js
Ext.define('App.window.DismissableWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    controller: 'dismissableWindow'
    // config ...
});
```

```js
Ext.define('App.window.DismissableWindowController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.dismissableWindow',

    listen: {
        global: {
            mousedown: 'dismissWindowCheck'
        }
    },

    dismissWindowCheck: function(ev){
        var view = this.getView();
        if(!view.owns(ev.getTarget()))
            view.close();
    }
});
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fg5)